# NullPointerException: at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.createAllFutures (DrawableContainer.java:881)

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, imageview

I am setting colorFilter to a custom view in my fragment which is causing a crash NPE crash in DrawableContainer.createAllFutures() function. Below is the stacktrace

```
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.createAllFutures (DrawableContainer.java:881)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.getOpacity (DrawableContainer.java:1166)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.getOpacity (DrawableContainer.java:436)
at android.widget.ImageView.isOpaque (ImageView.java:1744)
at android.view.View.invalidateInternal (View.java:17726)
at android.view.View.invalidate (View.java:17702)
at android.view.View.invalidate (View.java:17684)
at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable (ImageView.java:351)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.invalidateDrawable (DrawableContainer.java:403)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf (Drawable.java:488)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.setColorFilter (BitmapDrawable.java:675)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.setColorFilter (DrawableContainer.java:182)
at android.widget.ImageView.applyColorFilter (ImageView.java:1730)
at android.widget.ImageView.setColorFilter (ImageView.java:1670)
at android.widget.ImageView.setColorFilter (ImageView.java:1611)
at android.widget.ImageView.setColorFilter (ImageView.java:1623)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do share the file code, where crash is happening

Comment: The crash log you provided isn't related to your codes, so no one can help based on the data you are providing! Please share more details.

Comment: The createAllFeatures is a Library method. Look for the "Caused by" errors, or a crash log that includes your package name.